# Loop depending on the number of inputs but I dont know the amount of inputs

Tags: python, input, user-input, infinite-loop

I have this problem I want to solve: https://open.kattis.com/problems/doggopher.

The problem I have is that I don't understand how I am supposed to take the input if I don't know how many lines of gopher holes coordinates there will be. I want to make a loop that checks all the input coordinates and breaks the loop when a working hole is found but I don't understand how the program is supposed to know when I have put in all the coordinates. All the solutions I have found online claiming to be correct seem to just have an infinite loop whenever you only input one hole coordinate. Maybe I completely misunderstand the problem but I would like to get some clarification or guidance on how to solve that issue.

Edit*
Here is the code I am using right now in Python:

```
import sys


def distanceSquared(x, y, a, b):
    return (x - a) ** 2 + (y - b) ** 2


gx, gy, dx, dy = map(float, sys.stdin.readline().split())
notFound = True

try:
    while True:
        x, y = map(float, sys.stdin.readline().split())
        temp = 4 * distanceSquared(gx, gy, x, y)
        if temp < distanceSquared(dx, dy, x, y):
            print('The gopher can escape through the hole at (%.3f,%.3f).' % (x, y))
            notFound = False
except EOFError:
    pass


if notFound:
    print("The gopher cannot escape")
```

Comment: What language are you using? Python or Java? Also, can you please share the code you have so far?

Comment: You read your input until you reach the end of file.

Comment: I updated the post with my current Python code

Comment: What exactly has this to do with Java?

Comment: Oh, that was my bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following

```
import sys

def distanceSquared(x, y, a, b):
    return (x - a) ** 2 + (y - b) ** 2

gx, gy, dx, dy = map(float, sys.stdin.readline().split())
notFound = True

for line in sys.stdin:
    x, y = map(float, line.split())
    temp = 4 * distanceSquared(gx, gy, x, y)
    if temp < distanceSquared(dx, dy, x, y):
        print('The gopher can escape through the hole at (%.3f,%.3f).' % (x, y))
        notFound = False
        break

if notFound:
    print("The gopher cannot escape.")
```

Comment: That worked, did not know you can do that in Python

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  In the 3 answers you've posted so far over the last few hours, all are either mostly code with no explanation, appear likely to have been written (entirely or partially) by AI (e.g., ChatGPT), or both. A heads-up that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. For answers where you have not used AI, keep in mind that providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* your code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.